# I try send req from node.js to sql and i get null

Tags: sql, node.js

I'm trying to send `req` from node.js to sql and I get null, but if I execute this procedure from My-sql it returns ok response.
But then when I send this from node.js it returns null.

my code in node.js:

```js
 async getNumReportOfBid(bid,orderId,priceListId) {
    let bidTbl={pump:[{code:'b1644',description:'zementit',amount:5}]}
    let tvp = this._createTVPProductTree(bidTbl)
    let procParam = {tvp,priceListId,orderId}
    let procedureName = `[dbo].[pMainBidReq]`
 
    return await this._execProcedureWithTables(procedureName, procParam)
  }
```

my code in sql:

```
DECLARE @b productTree
INSERT INTO @b
VALUES('b1644','zementit',5),
('b1644','zementit',5)

DECLARE @n int

EXEC @n=pMainBidReq @b ,'1200001' ,27
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: Also add a tag for the dbms used.

Comment: How to add tag for the dbmes?